# How to deploy a non-http EventMachine based service on Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, nginx, passenger, eventmachine

There are examples how to deploy an EM based service *alongside* a normal HTTP service, backed by Passenger, eg [EventMachine and Passenger](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2011/05/04/eventmachine-and-passenger/). The HTTP component is activated by the HTTP service (nginx, apache), hosted/monitored by Passenger, and this activated component can then start the EM processing.

However I'm looking at some ideas how to deploy an EM-only based service (an UDP server). Something that does *not* respond to HTTP, so it does not live in the whole Apache/Nginx/Passenger environment.

Normally the answer would be 'just bring up your process and start the EM loop', but I don't want to miss on the goodness apache/nginx/passenger bring (init, start up, conf, logging, resource monitoring). Placing a 'ruby udp_server.rb' in init.d seems a bit primitive and prone to real-world deployment disasters (runaway process etc).

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with running a separate EM reactor for each apache process you can simply spawn it in the initializer, something in these lines:

https://gist.github.com/eatenbyagrue/1338545

If you need the EM service to be 1-per server, then you'll need to wrap it as a daemon process and possibly run it through an init.d script or God, see

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/daemonizing
https://github.com/mojombo/god

Alternatively, go for an all-in-1 deployment solution such as Torquebox (http://torquebox.org/) which has in-built support for running and management of long-running services